# What is the format for a secret file in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, credentials

I need to provide several credentials to a Jenkins job/pipeline and I want to upload them as a secret file to the global configuration for use as env variables in the Jenkinsfile. The creds would be basic database info (ports, hostname, passwords, etc...

What is the best filetype/format for this? json, yml?

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/ might help.